# Glide reflections on the complex plane

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Show that if a is real and non-zero then

a). $z → \bar z + a$ is a glide reflection along the real axis, and

b). $z → −\bar z + ia$ is a glide reflection along the imaginary axis.

Let $z = x+ yi$ where $x,y \in R$. From this,

$z → \bar z + a = x + a -yi$, Which is a reflection about the imaginary axis an a translation about the real axis.

and

$z → -\bar z + ia = -x + ai +yi$, Which is a reflection about the real axis and a translation about the imaginary axis.

Clearly neither of these seem to be glide reflections. I don't know how to proceed further than this. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, $z → \bar z$ which sends $x+yi$ to $x -yi$ is a reflection about the **real** axis, not the imaginary axis. Likewise, $z\to-\bar z$ is a reflection about the **imaginary** axis. The $+a$ and $+ia$ is a "glide" (or a translation) along the real and imaginary direction respectively, so combining them give you a glide reflection along the real/imaginary axis.

Comment: So I have to treat it like a composite of isometries to achieve the result? I suppose I was just interpreting this incorrectly.

Comment: That would be  a nice way to look interpret the transformation. You can look up the word "Affine Transformation" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

*By definition*, a glide reflection is composition of a translation by some vector $v$ and reflection in a line parallel to $v$ (composition order is immaterial; they commute)

The first map is composition of the reflection $z\mapsto \bar{z}$ and the translation $z\mapsto z+a$.

The second map is composition of reflection $z\mapsto -\bar{z}$ in $y$-axis, and translation $z\mapsto z+ia$